# create shared view model in zend framework 2 project

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I want to assign generic variables to the `view renderer` outside the controller action.

I'd prefer to handle this in the `module class bootstrap`.

My question is, how do I create a `view model` in the `module class bootstrap` that can be shared with the controller .

**My end result is to have the ability to add variables to the view model before we create a new instance of one inside the controller action.**

Here's something I started on, however `i cannot add variables to the declared viewmodel and have it persist to the controller's new instance of a view model`.

**Is there a way to create a view model and have it set as the renderer before dispatch.**

Here's something i started but if i can get it in the module class bootstrap instead id prefer that.

I dont think this works though.

```
    class BaseController extends AbstractActionController
    {
        protected $viewModel;

        public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e)
        {       
            $this->viewModel = new ViewModel([
                'module' => 'modulename',
                'controller' => 'controllername',
                'action' => 'actionname'
            ]);         
            parent::onDispatch($e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `Module.php` you have access to the `event` object.

In this event you can set some variables like this :

```
$event->getViewModel()->setVariable('isAdmin', $isAdmin);
$event->getViewModel()->setVariable('var', $var);
$event->getViewModel()->setVariable('form', $form);
$event->getViewModel()->setVariable('uri', $uri[0]);
```

If you want to test more you can also do :

```
$widgetTemplate = new ViewModel();
$widgetTemplate = $widgetTemplate->setTemplate('widget/container');
$event->getViewModel()->addChild($widgetTemplate, 'widget');
```

Those variables are available in your `layout.phtml`. I didn't test if it's the same `viewModel` available in your controller, give me a feedback if you test this solution.

For a variable defined in `module.php`, you can also use the `Zend\Container\Session` component to modify it in controllers